# The motion of a ball on a spinning turntable

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-kinematics

https://www.physics.harvard.edu/uploads/files/undergrad/probweek/sol21.pdf

I'm having some trouble understanding the logic going on in the solution given in the paper above. Particularly in equation (7):

[image]

I can understand the equations beforehand, but the jump they make from the first line for dv/dt to the next line, (7), I just can't follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to bring all terms with dv/dt to the left side of the equation. Do you then see the solution?